# How to efficiently get cell values from multiple DataFrames to insert into a master DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 different DataFrames (1 master DataFrame and 2 additional DataFrames). I am trying to add a column to my master DataFrame, with the elements of the column being different cell values in the other two DataFrames. I am using two columns of the master DataFrame to figure out which of the 2 DataFrames I need to get data from, and two more columns to act as indexes to a particular cell in the selected DataFrame.

```py
master_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M'],
    'col2': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'col3': ['X', 'Z', 'Z', 'X'],
    'col4': [2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]
})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    2021: [.632, .214, .987, .555],
    2022: [.602, .232, .287, .552],
    2023: [.932, .209, .347, .725],
    2024: [.123, .234, .9873, .5005]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    2021: [.6123, .2214, .4987, .555],
    2022: [.6702, .232, .2897, .552],
    2023: [.9372, .2, .37, .725],
    2024: [.23, .24, .873, .005]
})
```

For each row of the `master_df`, if the `col1` value is `'M'` and the `col3` value is `'X'`, I want to choose `df1`. If the `col1` value is `'F'` and the `col3` value is `'Z'`, I want to choose `df2`. Once I have selected the appropriate `DataFrame`, I want to use `col2` of the `master_df` as a row index and `col4` of the `master_df` as a column index. Finally, I will get the selected cell value and put it into the new column to be added to the `master_df`.

In this example, `master_df` should look like this at the end:

```py
master_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M'],
    'col2': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'col3': ['X', 'Z', 'Z', 'X'],
    'col4': [2021, 2022, 2023, 2024],
    'col5': [.632, .232, .37, .5005]
})
```

I have tried using a for loop to iterate through the `master_df`, but it is extremely slow since the `DataFrame`s that I'm working with have millions of rows each. Any efficient pandas solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `master_df` has only 2 combinations of value for `master_df.col1` and `master_df.col3`. Therefore, a simple `.lookup` and `np.where` will yield your desired output

```
df1_val = df1.lookup(master_df.col2, master_df.col4)
df2_val = df2.lookup(master_df.col2, master_df.col4)
master_df['col5'] = np.where(master_df.col1.eq('M') & master_df.col3.eq('X'), df1_val, df2_val)

Out[595]:
  col1  col2 col3  col4    col5
0  M    0     X    2021  0.6320
1  F    1     Z    2022  0.2320
2  F    2     Z    2023  0.3700
3  M    3     X    2024  0.5005
```

---

**Note**: if `master_df.col1` and `master_df.col3` have more than 2 combinations of values, you just need `np.select` instead of `np.where`

Comment: Thanks a lot, clean solution

Comment: @hbdch: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using a for loop, I wish it'll work for you

firs we'll make two filter for which dataframe to use

```
df1_filter = (master_df["col1"] == 'M') & (master_df["col3"] == 'X') 
df2_filter = (master_df["col1"] == 'F') & (master_df["col3"] == 'Z')
```

second, for each dataframe, we'll use the appropriate filter to get the values of interest
for df1

```
row1_index = master_df[df1_filter]["col2"]
col1_index = master_df[df1_filter]["col4"]
df1_values_of_interest = df1.iloc[row1_index][col1_index]
```

for df2

```
row2_index = master_df[df2_filter]["col2"]
col2_index = master_df[df2_filter]["col4"]
df2_values_of_interest = df2.iloc[row2_index][col2_index]
```

with this approache,the values of interest are going to be in the diagonal,so we'll try to get them (each one with it's appropriate index) and concatenate them

```
aa = pd.Series(np.diag(df1_values_of_interest), index=df1_values_of_interest.index)
bb = pd.Series(np.diag(df2_values_of_interest), index=df2_values_of_interest.index)
res = pd.concat([aa, bb])
```

finally, we'll add the result to the master df

```
master_df['col5'] = res
```

I hope the solution is clear,and it'll work for you.if you need more clarification don't hesitate to ask.
good luck !